# USB Camera is not working in kiosk

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode

I am working in project where we have to use USB camera. i added library ([UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera)) in project and in OTG Supported mobile device, camera is working fine, but in kiosk 55 inch screen  USB camera(USB Output wide-angle camera module) is in built  and my app is not showing any thing it detect usb camera but it is not showing preview.

```
   private final USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener 
   mOnDeviceConnectListener = new 
   USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(final UsbDevice device) {
       Toast.makeText(Usb_CameraActivity.this, "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        CameraDialog.showDialog(Usb_CameraActivity.this);

     }

    @Override
    public void onConnect(final UsbDevice device, final 
 USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock ctrlBlock, final boolean createNew) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v("TAG", "onConnect:");

     //  device.get

       mCameraHandler.open(ctrlBlock);
      Toast.makeText(Usb_CameraActivity.this, "onConnect", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(final UsbDevice device, final 
USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock ctrlBlock) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v("TAG", "onDisconnect:");
        if (mCameraHandler != null) {
            queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCameraHandler.close();
                }
            }, 0);
          //  setCameraButton(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDettach(final UsbDevice device) {
        //Toast.makeText(Usb_CameraActivity.this, "USB_DEVICE_DETACHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(final UsbDevice device) {

        //setCameraButton(false);
    }
}; 


 private void startPreview() {
    final SurfaceTexture st = mUVCCameraView.getSurfaceTexture();
   mCameraHandler.startPreview(new 
       Surface(st)); //// show usb camera preview but in kiosk camera 
nothing is showing


}
```

Comment: What is the output format of a webcam? kiosk support that video stream? Will encoder required to convert that stream? [see USB video device class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class), [see supported formats on android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network)

Comment: Supports SXGA, VGA, QVGA, CIF, QCIF, QVGA and QCIF format outputs.